# How to trigger alerts based upon timestamps in database?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

**Scenario:**

There's a task-manager application that allows its users to create tasks and associate a timestamp with it.

**Goal:**

The application is supposed to send email alerts to the users at the time when any of their tasks are due.

**Question:**

If there's a function in the application `sendEmailAlerts`, which queries database, fetches all those tasks which are due *now*, and send their creators alerts; *is it possible to trigger this function exactly at the moment when a task is due?*

The approach that I have in mind is to use a Quartz job, that would run every x minutes and invoke `sendEmailAlerts`. But this approach doesn't seem very efficient. Is there any better way of doing it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL Server Agent to create a job to execute at a specified time, although in this scenario i don't think it's optimal to create x jobs for x alerts.